# Query on WITH Clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, common-table-expression

I have a example query(fully modified) as below:

```
with projects as (

select * from projectdetails

)
select * from projects
```

when I run the above query, it is running fine.

But when i put one more select query..it is throwing error.

```
select * from 
(

with projects as (

select * from projectdetails


)

select * from projects

)
```

> Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is
>   a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change
>   tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated
>   with a semicolon.

The same query runs fine in Oracle but not in SQL server.

Comment: your simplified example doesn't really make any sense. as your wrapped outer query (if it were to work) would seemingly just do the same thing as `select * from projects`.

Comment: hi..I know that the above query is the same as select * from projects..but the actual question is writing an outer select with 'with' as sub query in it.When i wrote the same query in oracle it is allowing me to write but not in mysql..which was mentioned above.

Comment: @Sravan:- You cannot have a subquery having `with` clause in it. However if you can provide more details about what you are trying to achieve then may be you can find some other way to achieve that :)

Comment: Hi Rahul..by using with clause i get a field for all the projects which satisfies few conditions..the values in the field will be from  1 to 9.Now i need to calculate the count of  field which has values as 1,count of  field which has values from 2 to 5 and count of  field which has values from 5 to 9.so i am using three union clauses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query which you are trying to execute is called `Common Table Expression` and the the syntax which you are using is not the proper way of using it ie, you cannot use the `WITH` clause inside the `select` statement.

```
with projects as (

select * from projectdetails

)
select * from projects
```

The above query is fine and will work and the next query which you posted is neither correct and neither it is making sense as it is looking as if you are trying to do the same thing as above.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server and Oracle have different syntax requirements for common table expressions.

In Oracle, these can come before any `SELECT`.  In SQL Server, they need to come at the beginning of the query.  Hence, you cannot have a subquery with `WITH` in it.

Usually, you can just move the `WITH` statement before the first `SELECT` and the query will work in both databases.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what runs on Oracle, see supported [SQL Server SELECT syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

Simplified:

```
[ WITH { [ XMLNAMESPACES ,] [ <common_table_expression> ] } ]

SELECT select_list [ INTO new_table ]

[ FROM table_source ] [ WHERE search_condition ]

[ GROUP BY group_by_expression ]

[ HAVING search_condition ]

[ ORDER BY order_expression [ ASC | DESC ] ]
```

Full:

```
<SELECT statement> ::=  
    [ WITH { [ XMLNAMESPACES ,] [ <common_table_expression> [,...n] ] } ]
    <query_expression> 
    [ ORDER BY { order_by_expression | column_position [ ASC | DESC ] } 
  [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ <FOR Clause>] 
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ] 
<query_expression> ::= 
    { <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) } 
    [  { UNION [ ALL ] | EXCEPT | INTERSECT }
        <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) [...n ] ] 
<query_specification> ::= 
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ] 
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ] 
    < select_list > 
    [ INTO new_table ] 
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ] 
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ] 
    [ <GROUP BY> ] 
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```

If you don't know how to read this syntax directly you can generate `Railroad Diagrams` for every syntax definition from BOL examples below:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As other two answers speak about the syntax of CTE and their limitation, here is a way you would do this what you are trying to do, Multiple CTEs.

```
with projectdetails as (

select * from projectdetails


),projects AS

select * from projects

)
SELECT * FROM projects  --<-- here you select from Projects or projectdetails
```